# Library for UITableView forms

Tags: objective-c, ios, uitableview

I am in the painful process of creating a UITableView form (where people enter some information). The problem is that I have a couple of textfields (which is fine) but also dates, country selection, etc.

In order to do that, I need to write a custom animation to show a date picker, a country picker, etc. All of this makes the code complex to troubleshoot and uses a lot of small hard-coded tricks (field sizes, etc).

Is there a library that does this automatically? I would just have to set that a particular field is a Date and it would simply show a date picker instead of a keyboard. Or I could define a NSDictionary of the items (key - values) I'd like to display in a pickerview.

I already know about the example Apple provides regarding date picker, but it does not solve this problem.

Thank you for any help.

Comment: Why does it have to be an UITableView?

Comment: That's what is commonly used, but I'm open to any alternate suggestions as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://github.com/brunow/FormKit.m
This might be helpful

Comment: I'll definitely have to look at this one.

Comment: For people trying to install formkit, get the formkit directory then install 

'BWLongTextViewController', '~> 1.0'
'BWSelectViewController' 
'ActionSheetPicker-3.0', '~> 1.3.10'